# Handling redirects in Express to support nginx reverse proxy

Tags: node.js, express, nginx

I have an express application that is working perfectly on my local environment on port 3001. I need to deploy it on a production server running nginx listening on port 80. Below are some of the express routes

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    //home page, show login page
});


router.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    if(errors){
        //invalid credentials
        return res.redirect('..');
    }

    //successful login, redirect to admin area
    return res.redirect('../admin');
})
```

and similar routes for authenticated admin users. The routes are not working properly when deployed on nginx using reverse proxy. The nginx reverse proxy settings are as follows:

```
location /v2manager/ {
                proxy_set_header        Host    $host;
                proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:3001/;
        }
```

I want the application to be accessible on the route `v2manager` on my production domain like `example.com/v2manager`. So all the routes become as:

1. `example.com/v2manager/` for the home page
2. `example.com/v2manager/login` for login POST route, and
3. `example.com/v2manager/admin` for the admin area

However, the redirects are not working properly, on login failure the `return res.redirect('..')` redirects me to `example.com` which has a different page whereas it should redirect to `example.com/v2manager`

I can obviously change my application routes to add `v2manager` everywhere but the route `v2manager` can change frequently depending upon our environments and versioning. Also, a solution that would not hamper the local environment so that `localhost:3000/login` would work always

Answer (score 2):

You need set proxy redirect:

```
location /v2manager/ {
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_redirect ~/(.*)$ /v2manager/$1;
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001/;
}
```

Comment: Hi i having an issue with nginx, so currently when i access my ipaddress i go to the nginx welcome page but when i go to ipaddress/api i get 404 not found